# GROUP BY is creating multiple rows instead of 1

Tags: postgresql, group-by

This is in Postgresql 8.2 I created the following view and would like the results to be grouped together by the 'employee' field:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW stg.vw_dw_employees AS 
SELECT zvpa0001.pernr AS employee, 
CASE
WHEN zvpa0105.usrty::text = '0001'::text 
THEN max(zvpa0105.usrid::text)
ELSE NULL::text
END AS login, 
CASE
WHEN zvpa0001.sname IS NULL THEN              
max(upper(zvpa0001.ename::text))::character varying
ELSE zvpa0001.sname
END AS employee_name, 
CASE
WHEN zvpa0105.usrty::text = '0015'::text 
THEN max(zvpa0105.usrid::text)
ELSE NULL::text
END AS gid, 
CASE
WHEN zvpa0105.usrty::text = '0012'::text 
THEN max(zvpa0105.usrid::text)
ELSE NULL::text
END AS webkey
FROM src.zvpa0001
LEFT JOIN src.zvpa0105 
ON zvpa0001.pernr = zvpa0105.pernr
GROUP BY zvpa0001.pernr, zvpa0105.usrty, zvpa0001.sname, zvpa0001.persg;
```

When I query against the view I see multiple rows for the same employee. 
[image: Example]

I've tired a couple workarounds (joining with a subquery) but wasn't able to produce the needed results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why the cast `zvpa0001.ename::text`. What's the data type of the column? The table definition would clarify this and other questions. What you get with `\d zvpa0001` in psql.

Comment: Postgres 8.2? Really? You should plan an upgrade to a maintained version as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Group by doesn't create one row in all cases, it means that the employee 34 is grouped more than once based on the field you chose for the group function.

Try to reason on the logic behind your query

Answer (score 0):

> would like the results to be grouped together by the 'employee' field:

Then actually do that: `GROUP BY employee`

```
SELECT z1.pernr AS employee
     , CASE WHEN mine(z5.usrty::text) = '0001'
        THEN max(z5.usrid::text) END AS login
     , CASE WHEN min(z1.sname) IS NULL
        THEN max(upper(z1.ename::text))
        ELSE z1.sname END AS employee_name
     , CASE WHEN min(z5.usrty)::text = '0015'
        THEN max(z5.usrid::text) END AS gid
     , CASE WHEN min(z5.usrty)::text = '0012
        THEN max(z5.usrid::text) END AS webkey
FROM   src.zvpa0001      z1
LEFT   JOIN src.zvpa0105 z5 USING(pernr)
GROUP  BY employee;
```

All other columns need to part of an aggregate function.

I removed some noise, but the query is probably not ideal. Your casts are suspicious. If `z1.pernr` is the primary key you can simplify some more. But basic information is missing.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the advice. I figured it out though. The SELECT DISTINCT ON () did the trick.